# schema array in swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I have some problem with swagger. When I think I understand how it works, there's always something that doesn't work

What's wrong in thoses line

```
responses:
  '200':
    allOf:
    - $ref: '../index.yaml#/components/responses/200Ok'
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          allOf:
          - $ref: '../index.yaml#/components/schemas/Pagination'
          properties:
            data:
              type: array
              items:
                schema:
                  $ref: '../index.yaml#/components/schemas/Client'
```

The "data" property should be an array of the schema type given in the $ref, but this is the result

```
"data": [
  null
]
```

### EDIT

Ok, it seems that the right way is tu put the $ref directly under the items key, my problem was the use of a reserved key "status"
So, how can I use a reserved key in a object schema?

### EDIT

in my Client schema I put the property status two times, I didn't see that it was already there, so when I changed the property name it worked and I was thinking that maybe "status" was a reserved keyword.

Comment: What do you mean by "reserved key `status`"? There's no "status" in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. There are two issues:

1) You can't have `allOf` directly under a response code. You can `$ref` the whole response definition though.

2) You don't need `schema` under `items`.

Also, while putting `allOf` alongside other keywords is perfectly fine, some tools may like it better if all schemas being combined are listed *inside* `allOf`.

Try this version:

```yaml
responses:
  '200':
    description: OK
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          allOf:
          - $ref: '../index.yaml#/components/schemas/Pagination'
          - properties:
              data:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '../index.yaml#/components/schemas/Client'
```

Comment: My problem was that I declared a property two times in my schema. For the $ref I already found it, but thanks for your support, I upvoted your answer because it will be useful for other people

Comment: Also, the allOf under the response code works well, I use it to don't repeat everytime the description of the response. Also properties at the same level of allOf works well for me

Comment: `allOf` under response code is not valid syntax, don't rely on this. It's not supposed to work. If it actually works, it's a bug in the tool that you are using.

Comment: Ok, but how can I use the same description on different responses? Is there another way?

Comment: There's currently no way to reuse the response descriptions. Feel free to submit an enhancement request in the [OpenAPI Specification repository](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues).